# want level 2 category name in magento

Tags: php, magento, categories, catalog

```
 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
 $pro = $product->getCategoryName(); //category id is fetched here
 $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($pro);
```

- Root Catalog

  - Furniture
  - Electronics

    - Computer

      - Processor
  - Apparel

So when i get processor as category name, i want to display its level 2 category name that is Electronics

Answer (score 1):

got the solution, The code below will get the current category and then keep getting the parent category until it gets the highest category (but not the root category)

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
                    $pro = $product->getCategoryName(); //category id is fetched here

                    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($pro);

                    if ($category)
                    {
                        while($category->getLevel() != 2)
                        {
                            $category = $category->getParentCategory();
                            if (!$category)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if ($category)
                        {
                            echo $category->getName();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo 'Cannot find parent category';
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$CategoryCollection=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('level',2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addIsActiveFilter()
                ->addAttributeToFilter('level',2)
```

OR

```
<?php

$_category = Mage::registry('current_category');

$_category = $this->getCurrentCategory();

// Category Name

echo $_category->getName();

// Category Level

echo $_category->getLevel();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use something like this

```php
public function get_cat_from_product($prod_id, $level)
{
    $categoryIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prod_id)->getCategoryIds();
    if (count($categoryIds)) {
        $firstCategoryId = $categoryIds[$level - 1]; //level 2 -> pos 1
        $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($firstCategoryId);
        echo $_category->getName();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```